# Camel Cxf: How can I change the namespace of my incoming message?

Tags: java, cxf, apache-camel

I have to change the namespace of the incoming messages to our webservice.

The consumer route looks like the following:

```
from("cxf:/myservice?serviceClass=myServiceClass")...
```

I've tried to add somehow an interceptor to this(parameter properties.in, properties.inInterceptors?), but I don't get it how to configure it to my route.

We are not configuring our cxf endpoints in spring so I have to solve it with additional parameters to the route.
I think an interceptor with the transformation feature mentioned in the cxf documentation is the right solution, but I was not able to configure it correctly.

How can I add an interceptor to the route?
Or is there another way to change the namespace of the incoming message?

kind regards,
soilworker

Comment: Maybe I can use the cxfEndpointConfigurer option, but I was also not able to configure it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution:
It is possible to say something like from(endpoint), so I've created an instance of CxfEndpoint and there I can set the cxfEndpointConfigurer.
In this configurer I can add an interceptor which removes the namespace(see transformation feature of cxf).

Maybe it also works somehow with the from(uri) syntax, but I don't know how.